Can energy be captured from plasma?
My question is can energy be harvested directly from plasma. I also have another question, can plasma push objects?

Do solar panels count?

A plasma magnetohydrodynamic generator uses plasma as a moving conductor in place of the wire in conventional generators. In this application, the plasma pushes against the magnetic field, and ultimately against the stator.
Plasma thrusters use plasma pressure to move things.

One common way to harvest energy directly from a plasma is with a plasma cutter. The plasma conducts electricity to a work piece at a very high temperature. The plasma burns through the work piece. The current provides the energy that keeps the plasma hot.


I also have another question, can plasma push objects?

Yes sure, as plasma are ionized gases, so it has own pressure as normal gasses do and hence they can push objects around. As a proof are working pistons in combustion engines as part of burned-out fuel gas are converted into plasma, which pressure also pushes piston as an ordinary gases.
Also stars are not collapsing only because pressure created by their plasma compensates huge star self-gravity. And star layers pressure is by definition a "pushing upwards force", which keeps upper layers floating.
